# SharePoint 2013 App Part MVC View Presents 404

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, mvc, app-part, high-trust-app

I have developed a high-trust provider hosted app using the MVC framework to display a series of employee-focused KPI data widgets. Everything has been highly successful until I began implemented the App Parts (formally web parts -- iFrame views of the remote web application, for the uninitiated). The problem is specifically related to the routing, as I am able to successful view the application via the default route of each controller (using MVC attribute routing).

Results:

- Any action result specified in [Route("action=*TheView*")] is a success.

  - Elements.xml example:

    - Src="https://apps.domain.com/Dashboard/*TheView*/?{Standard Tokens}" is a **success**
    - Src="https://apps.domain.com/Dashboard/*TheOtherView*/?{Standard Tokens}" is a **404 The Resource can not be found**
    - Both URLs are accessible via web browser. Even explicitly revisiting the URL found in the web traffic logs (w/ parameters) is successful outside the context of SharePoint.

I certainly hope there is just some glaring, fundamental misunderstanding about using attribute routing in this scenario that I am not considering. However, I have received no useful error messages and none of my troubleshooting efforts have been successful.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you are using attribute routing.

Are you by any chance using [HttpGet] attribute on your ActionResult?

SharePoint addin does a POST to your web application. So just remove [HttpGet] attribute and let MVC handle it or change it to [HttpPost] if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was some obvious oversight caused by tired eyes. I was apparently not paying *too* much attention to those web traffic logs. You're a champion